# Incomplete Scraping on Webpage using Selenium Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape product data from a website which uses JS to load render HTML. I've used Selenium, with scrolling capabilities to the end of the page & time to reload the page but am still only able to scrape the top 8 products in the website.

Here's my code:

```
url = 'https://www.faire.com/retailer/r_9vkjixqbpq/category/Beauty%20&%20Wellness/subcategory/Bath%20&%20Body?filters=sorting%3Afeatured'
wd.get(url)

last_height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
time.sleep(3)


while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
  wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
  time.sleep(20)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
  new_height = wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  if new_height == last_height:
      break
  last_height = new_height

html = wd.page_source
soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
listings = soup.find('div', {'class': 'MarketplaceProductList__Wrapper-sc-3mfb9g-0 fWFKvm'}).findAll('div', {'class':'MarketplaceProductList__TileWrapper-sc-3mfb9g-2 fQbbTY'})

for item in listings: 
  product_name = item.find('span', {"class":"FallbackHandler__ContentParentWrapper-sk18il-2 jHwpkw"}).get_text(strip=True)
  print(product_name)
```

What can I do to extract information from every single product on the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you had to load parts of pages and then reach the end of page in-order to get the whole page source. So I had divided the page into 3 parts and scrolled through 2/3rd of the page You can also scroll to the end of the page but then why waste time and memory.

All the scraping can pretty much be done with `Selenium` itself as it gave a little cleaner output compared to `BS` but then if you use `re` module with BS you can make it look pretty too (I leave it to your choice)!

***Using Selenium***

```
url = 'https://www.faire.com/retailer/r_9vkjixqbpq/category/Beauty%20&%20Wellness/subcategory/Bath%20&%20Body?filters=sorting%3Afeatured'
wd.get(url)
sleep(3)
height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

#first scroll to load 1/3 rd of the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',height/3)
sleep(3)

#scroll to the next 1/3 rd of the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',height/3 + height/3)
sleep(3)

# by now all the scripts would've been loaded

#span tag has all the details you'll need
details = [i.text for i in wd.find_elements_by_tag_name('span') if len(i.text) > 0 and '\n' in i.text]
wd.quit()

for i in details:
    print(i)
    print()
```

*Output*

[image: Output for Selenium]

***Using Beautiful Soup***

```
url = 'https://www.faire.com/retailer/r_9vkjixqbpq/category/Beauty%20&%20Wellness/subcategory/Bath%20&%20Body?filters=sorting%3Afeatured'
wd.get(url)
sleep(3)
height = wd.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

#first scroll to load 1/3 rd of the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',height/3)
sleep(3)

#scroll to the next 1/3 rd of the page
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);',height/3 + height/3)
sleep(3)

#by now all the scripts would've been loaded

soup = BS(wd.page_source, 'lxml')
wd.quit()
#span tag has all the details you'll need
details = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('span') if len(i.text) >20 and 'MSRP $' in i.text]

#removing duplicates
details = list(dict.fromkeys(details))

for i in details:
    print(i)
    print()
```

*Output*

[image: Output using BS]